# Why AndroidAssetStudio generate my icon with different size unnormally?

Tags: android, icons, android-assets

My source icon was like below.
[image]

Than I want to get the different size of this image using AndroidAssetStudio Launcher Icon Generator.
But what I got was like below. The image was added the white edge that was annoying. How can get the normal image with different size. thanks.

[image]

Comment: Are you uploading a PNG icon image or what?

Comment: yes, a png image file.

Comment: Try setting `Shape` to **none**.

Comment: thanks. it works. I have another question. If I want to generate a variety of images for android app. Does It mean that I only need to create a image with 192*192 pixel(xxxhi), than transmit them to xxhi,xhi,etc.